# Python how to rerun code after it stops

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, cmd, try-catch

i am newbie to Programming,i am running this python code in my computer Normally it runs correctly, but sometimes the code stops due to network conditions. once it stopped i have to run the code manually. Does anyone know how to modify this code to retry if the code fails to run

This is the code

```
for line in f:
    api.update_status(line)
    time.sleep(1200)
```

Answer (score 2):

The code in Noel's answer makes it more likely that the program doesn't stop until the loop goes through every item in `f`.

The problem though is that an exception could occur in the line after `except` and the program would stop again.

try this:

```
i = 0

while i < len(f):
    try:
        api.update_status(f[i])
        i += 1
    except:
        pass
```

This way, `i` only gets incremented if `api.update` is successful so no items will be skipped and the program wont stop until all `f` are `update`d

Comment: Exactly what i stated in the previous answer and i found no way to make such a loop work. Thanks.
@leonardo19 you should keep the trick for next times, you'll certainly need it again.

Comment: While running The Code i get this warning message and the code runs

   C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning

Comment: Did you try installing the dependencies as advised on the page the link points to?

Comment: pip install --upgrade ndg-httpsclient